# Add character array to const string& in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, character

```
char stringToAdd[4097] = ""; 

// some manipulations on stringToAdd to add some value to it. 

if(stringToAdd[0] != '\0') { 
response = MethodCalledHere("Some Random text");
}

MethodCalledHere(const String& inputParameter) {
 // some method definition here.
}
```

I've to add stringToAdd to the "Some Random text". Something like -

```
response = MethodCalledHere("Some Random text" + stringToAdd);
```

But this gives me error that 
'+' cannot add two pointers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `std::stringstream`, or encapsulate the first string in a constructor...

Comment: Or use a `std::string` literal

Comment: The C++14 cool cats use `""s + "Some Random text" + stringToAdd;` Note the built in user defined literal. Unlike the + abomination in Java, this is not a kludge.

Comment: @Charles - How exactly are you suggesting?

Comment: @Bathsheba - This seems like fixing the error but I didn't get the concept. If you can explain a bit.

Comment: Google "user defined literal std::string".

Answer (score 2):

> But this gives me error that '+' cannot add two pointers.

That's because in that context, both sides of the `+` operator are pointers.

Use

```
response = MethodCalledHere(std::string("Some Random text") + stringToAdd);
```

If your function expects `char const*`, then, you can construct a `std::string` first and then use `std:string::c_str()`.

```
std::string s = std::string("Some Random text") + stringToAdd;
response = MethodCalledHere(s.c_str());
```

If you are able to use C++14, you can use the string literal (Thanks are due to @Bathsheba for the suggestion).

```
response = MethodCalledHere("Some Random text"s + stringToAdd);
```

Comment: This is closed so I can't answer, but feel free to wack in the C++14 way: see my question comment. Nice answer though as it is, have an upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba, thanks for the suggestion. Hope the modified expression is still valid.

Comment: it's better than the way I had it.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto MethodCalledHere(std::string inputParameter) {
    inputParameter.append(stringToAdd, 
                          stringToAdd + std::strlen(stringToAdd));
    return inputParameter;
}
```